# Enable DB context logging in .net core with entity framework 2.2

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a dot net core 2.1 console application which uses entity framework 2.2

I want to enable logging for the DB context to see the query execution. The DB used is MySql. I tried other links on this but I am not getting result with any of the solutions provided in them. Please let me know correct way of doing this with entity framework version 2.2

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` version `2.2.6` (or another provider compatible with EF Core 2.2.6), then take a look at the following fully working console sample app, the demonstrates how to use `UseLoggerFactory`, `LoggerFactory` and `ConsoleLoggerProvider` with a filter:

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    public class IceCream
    {
        public int IceCreamId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<IceCream> IceCreams { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseMySql(
                    "server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;user=root;password=;database=So63898775",
                    b => b.ServerVersion("8.0.20-mysql"))
                .UseLoggerFactory(
                    new LoggerFactory(
                        new[] {new ConsoleLoggerProvider((_, level) => level >= LogLevel.Information, true)}))
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<IceCream>().HasData(
                new IceCream {IceCreamId = 1, Name = "Vanilla"},
                new IceCream {IceCreamId = 2, Name = "Chocolate"});
        }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            using (var context = new Context())
            {
                context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();

                var iceCreams = context.IceCreams.ToList();

                Debug.Assert(iceCreams.Count == 2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It uses the following `csproj` file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="2.2.6"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="2.2.6"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="2.2.0"/>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

In later versions, the syntax to setup logging has changed.

---

For further information, see [Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging?tabs=v2).